# Прозрачная надпись в кнопке средствами CSS

Tags: css, button, opacity

Привет!

Можно ли средствами CSS создать кнопку, надпись в которой будет прозрачной, то есть чтобы сквозь нее было видно задний фон? Саму кнопку сделать прозрачной могу, а надпись не соображу как.

[image: Пример]

Comment: думается только свг

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: url(http://www.crystalxp.net/galerie/img/img-wallpapers-colors-krystof-----15400.jpg) repeat;
  margin:10px;
}
h1 { 
  background-color:#fff; overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block; 
  padding:10px; 
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:200px;
}
span { 
  background: url(http://www.crystalxp.net/galerie/img/img-wallpapers-colors-krystof-----15400.jpg) -20px -20px repeat;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>ABCDEFGHIKJ</span></h1>
```

[Смотрите тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-cut-out-of-background)

Comment: Отличное решение. Только IE как всегда идет лесом

Comment: @tutankhamun
по ссылке есть ответы с SVG и другие, думаю ТС поберет вариант, который ему нужен из предоставленного